# Getting error on histogram plot in R Programming

Tags: r, histogram

**R PROGRAMMING - Trying to visualize the number of flights by destination, in decreasing order, that departed from JFK airport.**

```
flights_dest <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(flights_newvar$dest)))
print(flights_dest)

ordered_flight_dest <- flights_dest[order(-flights_dest$Freq), ]
print(ordered_flight_dest)

hist(ordered_flight_dest$carrier)
```

Getting error on my histogram. Can anyone help?

Comment: A histogram is the count for a continuous independent variable.  The airline carrier is a discrete category variable, thus you need a bar or column chart.

Comment: As @Dave2e said, you want a barplot here. Try `barplot(ordered_flight_dest$carrier)` instead.